# Bash script for plotting multiple files with Gnuplot

Tags: shell-script, scripting, terminal, gnuplot

I want to plot several files just executing a bash script which calls Gnuplot. My idea of a possible bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot
plot 'my_first_file.dat' u 1:2
replot 'my_second_file.dat' u  1:2
```

let us call this bash script `gnuplot_script.sh`.

When I execute this script via `$./gnuplot_script.sh`  I only get gnuplot open in my terminal without the plots related to the script.

What should I modify in the script in order to have my data plotted?
This is my first time in the world of bash scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the lines

```
plot 'my_first_file.dat' u 1:2
replot 'my_second_file.dat' u  1:2
```

Specifying the input for a command does not work as you tried in your script.

You can pass these as input to `gnuplot` as a "[here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)".

shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot << EOF
plot 'my_first_file.dat' u 1:2
replot 'my_second_file.dat' u  1:2
EOF
```

Or you can write the commands for `gnuplot` into a separate file and pass the file name as a command line argument to `gnuplot`, e.g. `gnuplot file.plot`. (The file does not need to be named `.plot`.)

You can also create a script that is interpreted by `gnuplot` instead of a shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
plot 'my_first_file.dat' u 1:2
replot 'my_second_file.dat' u  1:2
```

Make this script executable and run it by typing its name like `./script` or `/path/to/script` as you would run a shell script. (See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15234086/10622916)